# Error 'Plugin-Version' of 'unspecified' for 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@27e0e84c' is not a valid version number

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, ionic-framework

i added Firebase cloud messaging plugin to my ionic project when i run the project using

> ionic cordova run android

i get this error

```
> Configure project :app
Error 'Plugin-Version' of 'unspecified' for 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@27e0e84c' is not a valid version number

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script '../platforms/android/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/starter-FCMPlugin.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot invoke method lastIndexOf() on null object

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it?